# How to monitor SMS, Email and a call coming?

Tags: ios, email, sms

I want to write an app monitor whether a sms(or iMessage), an email or a calls coming? I know public framework (CoreTelephony) monitor a calls, but it not work in background for a long time. Then how to monitor sms and email? Thanks!

Comment: There is no public API to achieve what you want.  If you insist on this feature then you will have to jailbreak.

Comment: Message access profile(MAP for short) achieve it?

Comment: MAP has nothing to do with this, it is a profile for sending bluetooth messages.